# Merging two UIImage into 1 to be savedtolibrary

Tags: ios, uiimage

I would like to know how can I merge 2 uiimage into 1? I would like to save the end product to the library. For saving images I'm using a UI button. Here's snippet of how I save a UIImageview.image.

```
-(IBAction)getPhoto:(id)sender  {

UIImage* imageToSave = imageOverlay.image;

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

I've looked online and read about UIGraphicsBeginImageContext. Found an example but I couldn't understand how to actually apply it to mine. Here's the one I've got so far.

```
- (UIImage*)addImage:(UIImage *)image secondImage:(UIImage *)image2 
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
[image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(10,10,image2.size.width,image2.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
}
```

Right now I have 2 UIImageviews which is imageOverlay.image and imageView.image. If I use the method above how to assign the return value to UIImageWriteToSavedPhotoAlbum? Hope someone can point me to the right direction.

Thanks very much.

Comment: very helpful...worked like charm.

Comment: this addImage action helped me to combine 200 images to one.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you don't have the header for the method in your header file, in the .h file of the class/view controller  from which you're running the IBAction, add the first line of your method, -(UIImage*) addImage:... And end it with a ; before the @end. That should work, though you'd have to implement it in the .m file of the same .h file somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-(IBAction)getPhoto:(id)sender  {

UIImage* imageToSave = [self addImage:imageOverlay.image secondImage:imageView.image];

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: Hi, just tried your code. It gave me this warning: "getPhotoController may not respond to -addImage:SecondImage". getPhotoController is the class name. Is there anything else I might be missing or done something wrong?

Comment: You must put : `- (UIImage*)addImage:(UIImage *)image secondImage:(UIImage *)image2 ;` in your header (the getPhotoController.h file).

Comment: Now, I'm getting a SIGABRT. Not sure how to read the debug to find out the problem. I've put the - (UIImage *) bit in the header file and your first answer in my method. I have the log from the console. Here's the last bit of the log: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: Verify if both of the images are not `nil`.

Comment: I'm really sorry about this but I must be that much of a noob. What do you mean by verify both images are not nil?

Comment: Hi Danutz Ch, I've read more about using UIImageView.images. At no point I've set imageOverlay.image = nil. Building it however game me these warnings: 1. Method definition for 'addImage:secondImage:'not found. 2. Incomplete implementation of class 'getPhotoController'. Is there anything I'm still missing?

Comment: Hi hakimo, I know it might be an obvious thing, but have you checked if the name of your method is getPhoto:.... or getPhotoController:..... seems like the compiler cannot find either the declaration of your method (that is the bit you add to your .h file), it can't find the method in your .m file, or there's a misspelling of either one. make sure everything is exactly the same.  In regards to the pictures being nil, alloc init both pictures and pass them through the method, then make sure you release them if you're not using auto-referencing.

Answer (score 1):

create a NSLog, and pass them through it like this, image1 and image2 are your images:

```
NSLog (@"testing images aren't nil. Details for image1: %@ image2: %@",image1,image2);
```

I'm a newbie too, and I don't really know a more sophisticated way to see if the image is nil, but I saw that by passing a nil image to the statement above, you'd only get nil instead of the values of those two images. If you get lots of information, even though they're alot of codes and you may not understand them either, as I usually don't, at least you can test whether they are nil or not.