# Image shrinks when one image views merges with other image view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

I want to append 2 images from 2 image views both are having same frame

**1** . Bottom image view:  **imageView1**

**2** . Top Image view : ***`imageView2`***

I have a background image on **imageView1** and draw paint on ***`imageView2`***

At one point i need to append images on **imageView1** and ***`imageView2`*** and displayed only on **imageView1**.

I merge / append both image using following code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView1.bounds.size);
[imageView1.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
[imageView2.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
lastSavedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

imageView1.image = lastSavedImage;
```

But after merging the output image is shrinks 1pixel every time....

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by following the  Vlad answer from:

[How to combine/ merge 2 images into 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257992/how-to-combine-merge-2-images-into-1?rq=1)

*

```
- (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImage:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage {
    UIImage *image = nil;
    CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstImage.size.width, secondImage.size.width), MAX(firstImage.size.height, secondImage.size.height));
    if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize); 
    }
    [firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-firstImage.size.width)/2), 
                                        roundf((newImageSize.height-firstImage.size.height)/2))]; 
    [secondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-secondImage.size.width)/2), 
                                         roundf((newImageSize.height-secondImage.size.height)/2))]; 
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

*